# How to call method with "self" parameter?

Tags: python

I need to call a function method complete_login:

```
class VKOAuth2Adapter(OAuth2Adapter):  
    ...

    def complete_login(self, request, app, token, **kwargs):
    ...
```

It should be really easy, but i cant understand what parameter should be send in "self". I know why its there, but how to call such method?

```
login = VKOAuth2Adapter.complete_login( ??? , request, app, token)
```

Thanks.

Comment: you don't need to put anything - `self` is implied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make an **instance** of the class:

```
v = VKOAuth2Adapter( whatever parameters it needs, if any )
```

and then you'll call:

```
v.complete_login(request, app, token)
```

where `v` will automatically become the method's `self`.

Answer (score 4):

The `self` parameter is usually not passed explicitly when calling a Python method--it is implicit.  So you'd do this:

```
vk = VKOAuth2Adapter()
vk.complete_login(req, app, token)
```

The `vk` instance will be passed as `self`.  You could write the code this way too:

```
vk = VKOAuth2Adapter()
VKOAuth2Adapter.complete_login(vk, req, app, token)
```

But that would not be considered normal practice in Python, so use the first option.

Note that if you are calling the method from inside another method in the same class, you'd do it this way:

```
self.complete_login(req, app, token)
```

That's because `self` would be an instance of the class, just as `vk` was in my previous examples.