# Unable to figure out the right way while using a customized method within scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the title of different posts from their innerpages from a website using scrapy in combination with selenium, although the content of this site is static. The script grabs the links of different posts from the landing page and reuses the newly parsed links to fetch titles from their innerpages.

I know there is a [library](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium) which is meant for using selenium within scrapy. However, I'm not interested in using that library for this basic use case.

There are two methods within the following spider. I could stick with one method to do the whole thing but I used two methods here to understand how can I pass the links from one method to another in order to do the rest of the things within latter method without making any requests, as in `scrapy.Request()`.

The script appears to be working correctly. The script also works correctly if I kick out `yield` from here `yield self.parse_from_innerpage(response.urljoin(elem))` and use like `self.parse_from_innerpage(response.urljoin(elem))`.

***Question: should I use yield or not within parse method to go on with current implementation as they both work interchangeably?***

I've tried with:

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class StackoverflowSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "stackoverflow"

    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver,15)

    def parse(self, response):
        for elem in response.css(".summary .question-hyperlink::attr(href)").getall():
            yield self.parse_from_innerpage(response.urljoin(elem))

    def parse_from_innerpage(self,link):
        self.driver.get(link)
        elem = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1[itemprop='name'] > a")))
        print(elem.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0',
        'LOG_LEVEL':'ERROR',
    })
    c.crawl(StackoverflowSpider)
    c.start()
```

Comment: Your `parse_from_innerpage` method doesn't return anything (meaning it returns a None). This probably causes a generator that returns many None objects. Instead of using print, return elem.text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def parse_from_innerpage(self,link):
        self.driver.get(link)
        elem = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1[itemprop='name'] > a")))
        print(elem.text)
```

Before trying to answer your question, I want to add a slight note about your `print()` statement inside the `parse_from_innerpage(self, link)` function. Though this topic is [controversially discussed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/164728/is-it-bad-practice-to-output-from-within-a-function) it's a better practice to return the object in question - you can later decide to print it by [assigning a class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895784/how-to-call-method-with-self-parameter) (and then calling the method) or just directly by `Class.Method(**args)`

That out of the way - let's tackle your question:

> Should I use yield or not within parse method to go on with current implementation as they both work interchangeably?

To answer this - or rather understand the reply - I highly suggest to look at some qualitative resources in order to grasp the concept of `yield`. What follows are a few links for **further reading** purposes:

- [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)
- [Official Python documentation for the "yield" statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement)
- [GeeksForGeeks Blog about "Yield vs. Return"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-yield-keyword-instead-return-keyword-python/)

Basically, `return` send a specified value back, `yield` on the other hand produces a *sequence* of values - hence perfect for iterating over the values you obtain.

---

**Let's look at your code:**

`parse(self, response) method`:

```
def parse(self, response):
        for elem in response.css(".summary .question-hyperlink::attr(href)").getall():
            yield self.parse_from_innerpage(response.urljoin(elem))
```

Simply put, this method expects some values from `parse_from_innerpage(self, link)` as it "*yields*" or iterates through the receives list. **However**, your `parse_from_innerpage(self,link)` doesn't return anything - take a look, there is **no** `return` statement!:

```
def parse_from_innerpage(self,link):
        self.driver.get(link)
        elem = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1[itemprop='name'] > a")))
        
        #Use return instead of print()
        print(elem.text)
```

As `parse_from_innerpage(**args)` returns `None`, `parse(**args)` won't return anything either, as there is nothing to iterate over/return. Hence you should replace `print()` with `return`.

---

I suggest looking at the [Scrapy Documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html) (especially the [Scrapy at a glance](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html?)) to understand how Scrapy exactly works and what it expects a `scrapy.Spider` to do in order to achieve your goals. Basically the `parse(**args)` method is used as a generator (referring to the [already mentioned StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)) for the results you want to obtain - once no elements are there to iterate over (it stops) it *"shows them to you"*:

> In the parse callback, we loop through the quote elements using a CSS
> Selector, yield a Python dict with the extracted quote text and
> author, look for a link to the next page and schedule another request
> using the same parse method as callback

*... but as mentioned in your case `parse(**args)` unfortunately receives `None` due to `print()` instead of `return`.*

Answer (score 1):

`yield` in python is used from inside a generator to "give up" on running and return a value.

so here the `parse` method returns the result of `parse_from_innerpage`. However, `parse_from_innerpage` does not have a return statement, which means it returns `None`.

Read [this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html?highlight=wait#what-just-happened) from the scrapy documentation about what scrapy expects a spider to do.

In short, scrapy uses the `parse` method as a generator for the results and then shows them to you when it stops running (runs out of links to scrape).
Replace the `print` with returns and everything should work as expected